# Find used number combinations in a string

Tags: python, string, sequence

I want to check non-consecutive numbers in Python.

For example, in a string containing 1,2,3,4,5,8, I want to check if any two digit combination has been used.
I can find 1,2 and 5,8 but I cannot find a combination of 1,3 or 4,8 or 3,1, etc.

Below is my code:

```
# An example of a single user key is 1,2 another example is 5,8
# Numbers used to make combinations of two digit keys so far.
used_keys = '1,2,3,4,5,8'
    
# User key input.
user_key =input("Enter your new key: ")

# Check if the key combination has been used before.
if user_key in used_keys:
    print ("Your chosen key ("  + user_key + ") already exists.")
else:
    print("Key accepted.")
```

My expected result is:

1. When a user inputs a new key as 1,2 the program prints "key already exists". (Correct, the 1,2 combo can be made using the numbers in the string.)
2. When a user inputs a new key as 1,9 the program prints "Key accepted". (Correct, the 1,9 combo cannot be made using the numbers in the string.)

THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.

3. When a user inputs a new key as 1,3 the program prints *key accepted* .(Incorrect, the program must print *key already exists*, the 1,3 combo can be made using the numbers in the string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming unique keys, it's trivial to solve this with [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) operations:

```
used_keys = '1,2,3,4,5,8'
# convert the string to a set of the digits/numbers
keys = set(used_keys.split(','))
# {'1', '2', '4', '5', '8'}

user_key = input("Enter your new key: ")
if set(user_key.split(',')).issubset(keys):  # check if input is a subset
    print(f"Your chosen key ({user_key}) already exists.")
else:
    print("Key accepted.")
```

*NB. assuming a strict `1,2`-like format, you must ensure other characters are not used in the input.*

Examples:

```
Enter your new key: 1,3
Your chosen key (1,3) already exists.

Enter your new key: 1,9
Key accepted.
```

If you have duplicated keys, same logic with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

used_keys = '1,2,2,4,5,8'
keys = Counter(used_keys.split(','))

user_key = input("Enter your new key: ")
if Counter(user_key.split(',')) < keys:
    print(f"Your chosen key ({user_key}) already exists.")
else:
    print("Key accepted.")
```

Examples:

```
Enter your new key: 2,2
Your chosen key (2,2) already exists.

Enter your new key: 4,4
Key accepted.
```

Comment: Hi @mozway, 

Thank you, it solved my issue but took away a working part.
Every key combo I use now shows already exists.

Enter your new key: 1,9
Your chosen key (1,9) already exists. 

Previous Output:

Enter your new key: 1,9
Key accepted.

Comment: @Ostik make sure to refresh your page and use the latest version of my code. I initiated mistyped `used_keys` in place of `user_key` ;)

Answer (score -1):

The issue with your current code is that it checks if the entire user_key string is present in the used_keys string. It does not consider the order of the numbers. To achieve your desired result, you should check for each individual digit in the user_key separately.

Here's an updated version of your code:

> python code

```
# Numbers used to make combinations of two-digit keys so far.
used_keys = '1,2,3,4,5,8'

# User key input.
user_key = input("Enter your new key: ")

# Split the user_key into individual digits.
user_digits = user_key.split(',')

# Check if each digit in the user_key has been used before.
if all(digit in used_keys for digit in user_digits):
    print("Your chosen key (" + user_key + ") already exists.")
else:
    print("Key accepted.")
```

This code splits the user_key into individual digits using the split`(',')` method. Then, it checks if each digit is present in the used_keys string. The `all()` function ensures that all digits must exist in used_keys for the entire key to be considered already existing.